# What is the recommended way to connect to HBase using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, hbase

I need to read HBase and process data using Python. I understand Java is the standard way to connect to HBase, and google searches did not lead to a solution for me. If possible, please point me to a working example of using Python with HBase?

Answer (score 4):

You can use happybase.

```
import happybase
conn = happybase.Connection(host = host)
conn.open()
table = conn.table(table_name)
rows = table.scan(filter=filter_str, row_start=row_start, row_stop=row_stop)
```

Your scan result will be stored in the rows dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the package [happybase](https://happybase.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package to access HBase and perform some basic operations.

However, happybase might not be updated with the latest HBase API changes. A safer option is to use the official HBase [REST API](https://hbase.apache.org/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/rest/package-summary.html) which supports the standard CRUD operations or the auto-generated Python client code that the [Apache Thrift](https://thrift.apache.org/) compiler gives you.